# Using Prism in ElementHost

Tags: vb.net, winforms, prism

Can anyone suggest what might be missing from the following code. I am getting nothing displayed on my WinForm.

I have looked at the following related posts on this topic but they haven't solved the issue for me.

- [How to use Prisim within an ElementHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363369/how-to-use-prisim-within-an-elementhost)
- [Problems with Prism hosted in a WinForm ElementHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935701/problems-with-prism-hosted-in-a-winform-elementhost)

**WinForm with ElementHost**

```
    Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    '   WPF application instance
    _wpfApplication = Application.Current()

    If Application.Current Is Nothing Then
        _wpfApplication = New Application()
    End If

    '   Load the application modules
    Dim unityBootstrapper As New Bootstrapper()
    unityBootstrapper.Run()

    '   Bind the shell to the ElementHost
    Dim shellElement = unityBootstrapper.Container.Resolve(Of Shell)()
    ehMaster.Child = shellElement

End Sub
```

**Bootstrapper**

```
Public NotInheritable Class Bootstrapper
Inherits UnityBootstrapper

Protected Overrides Function CreateShell() As DependencyObject
    Return New Shell
End Function

Protected Overrides Function GetModuleCatalog() As IModuleCatalog
    Dim catalog As ModuleCatalog = New ConfigurationModuleCatalog()
    catalog.AddModule(GetType(Pitchbook.Excel.ChartWizardModule))
    Return catalog
End Function

End Class
```

**Shell**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Shell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF">
<DockPanel>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="HeaderRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="HeaderRegion" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="auto">

    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="LeftRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="LeftRegion" Width="auto" DockPanel.Dock="Left">

    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MainRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">

    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
</UserControl>

Partial Public Class Shell
Inherits UserControl

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

End Class
```

**ChartWizardModule**

```
Public NotInheritable Class ChartWizardModule
Implements IModule

Private ReadOnly regionManager As IRegionManager

Public Sub Initialize() Implements IModule.Initialize
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", GetType(Test))
End Sub

Public Sub New(regionManager As IRegionManager)
    Me.regionManager = regionManager
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't pay enough attention to this post
[How to use Prisim within an ElementHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363369/how-to-use-prisim-within-an-elementhost)

The issue is that you need an Application.Current that is not null and **is not equal to typeof(Application)**.

Therefore I created the following class

```
Public Class WpfApplicationAdapter
    Inherits Windows.Application

    '   HACK - This class shouldn't be required. Look out for a resolution to this in future WPF versions.

End Class
```

And changed my WinForm constructor to the following

```
    Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    If Application.Current Is Nothing Then
        Dim wpfAppAdapter As New WpfApplicationAdapter
    End If

    '   Load the application modules
    Dim formBootstrapper As New Bootstrapper
    formBootstrapper.Run()

    '   Get the current instance of shell and bind it to the ElementHost
    Dim shellElement = formBootstrapper.Container.Resolve(Of Shell)()
    ehMaster.Child = shellElement

End Sub
```